# "Logs can only be viewed for the account logged in" in AWS CloudWatch Logs console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

After enabling cross-account, cross-region access (in AWS CloudWatch Settings) in both the monitoring account and the sharing account, I receive an error in the CloudWatch Logs console upon selecting the sharing account from the drop-down at the top of the page:
"Logs can only be viewed for the account logged in - XXX. You are viewing data for YYY.Go back to XXX in us-east-1"

Viewing cross-account *metrics* and *dashboards* are working well, but *logs* are most useful to my use case. What could cause this error on the console?

I have the monitoring and sharing roles set up per the instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Cross-Account-Cross-Region.html#enable-cross-account-cross-Region

Comment: I got the exact same problem. Sharing metrics, alarms and dashboards is ok. But I'm stuck with this error when I try to access Logs for another account.

Comment: Same problem here! No solution found yet.

Comment: The same problem(

Comment: I'm running into the same issue 9 months later. Cross-account Cloudwatch access is not very useful without logs sharing :/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as at time of writing (2021-12-22), cross-account CloudWatch only supports dashboards, alarms, metrics and automatic dashboards. Logs are not yet visible across accounts.

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Cross-Account-Cross-Region.html), my emphasis:

> This functionality provides you with cross-account visibility to your *dashboards, alarms, metrics, and automatic dashboards* without having to log in and log out of different accounts.

Answer (score 0):

With [CloudWatch cross-account observability](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Unified-Cross-Account.html) you should be able see logs from another account.

Note: [CloudWatch cross-account observability](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Unified-Cross-Account.html) and [Cross-account cross-Region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Cross-Account-Cross-Region.html) are different features.